# Error on converting Latin-1 to UTF-8 String in Python 3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, text-processing, iso-8859-1

I have a text dataset that can be imported by pandas only by using the encoding **Latin-1**, when I try to use another encodings, it results error. I would like to clear the special characters from that dataset. However, those special characters appears in the hex form like this:

```
AKU\n\nKU \xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84
```

Then I saw on another thread that I can get rid of this by decoding this to Latin-1, then encode to UTF-8. But it resulted error as shown in the image.

```py
x = data.iloc[5, 0].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-c80119246806> in <module>()
      1 print(data.iloc[5, 0])
----> 2 x = data.iloc[5, 0].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
      3 if True:
      4   x = re.sub("[\n\t]", ' ', x)
      5   x = re.sub("\d+", ' ', x)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Basically, how can I convert that to UTF-8 for the next steps for text processing? Or is there any other way to get rid of those without need of convertion? Thank you

[image: Error appears like this]

Comment: It isn't `latin1` but `utf-8` as `'AKU\n\nKU \xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` returns `'AKU\n\nKU '`. Try `utf-8-sig` while inporting by pandas…

Comment: When I tried importing with the encoding `utf-8-sig` it returns an error.  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1389: invalid continuation byte`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import codecs
print(codecs.decode(data.iloc[5, 0], 'unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZowTvt):

```py
import codecs
text = r'AKU\n\nKU \xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84\xf0\x9f\x98\x84'
print(codecs.decode(text, 'unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))
# => AKU\n\nKU
```